# Models association help in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, model, model-associations

I'm currently developing a project using CakePHP where users can create projects. Each project has only one administrator user, but other users should be able to "view" the project. How should I create this "view" option to users?
I've already done the following model associations:
[Users Model] hasMany [Projects] (by the time each user can have many projects).

I'm kinda perplexed now and I don't know exactly what additional model association i should create :/ I think a belongsTo or a HasAndBelongsToMany but i'm not sure :/ Can you help me out here?

thank you in advance!

Comment: you can add new field is_admin in Users to make a difference between administrator user and normal users

Comment: Can any user view any project or is there another piece of logic that limits which projects a user can view?

Comment: this way, any user can view any project (and just have a difference between admin and normal user). What I need is each project to be viewable from it's admin and it's members (not any other user in the platform). {Till now, only admins can view their own projects, and of course not other's admins' projects}

Comment: Your data model is missing a piece - the part regarding projects having members. Can a user be a member of more than 1 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have 3 database tables

1. **users**
2. **projects** - This table needs to have a column (administrator) which contains the user_id representing the user who is the administrator
3. **usersprojects** - This table is cross reference table between the users and projects representing the members of a project

**CakePHP Models**

***User***

```
public $useTable = 'users';
public $hasMany = array(
    'ProjectAsAdmin' => array(
       'className' => 'Project')
  );
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'ProjectAsMember' => array(
       'className' => 'Project')
  );
```

***Project***

```
public $useTable = 'projects';
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Member' => array(
       'className' => 'User')
 );
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Administrator' => array(
       'className' => 'User',
       'foreignKey' => 'administrator'
     )
  );
```

Comment: i'm implementing this right now, wait for feedback and thank you for your very precise response!!